# Change the style of the drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a 4 drop down list based on each drop down value the other drop down will change i tried to change the style of the drop down list using CSS and jquery and javascript.
I almost got the style of the drop down and the functionality also works fine, but where i am stuck is 
In the jquery what is done is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("select").each(function(){
    $(this).wrap('<div class="selectbox"/>');
    $(this).after("<span class='selecttext'></span><span class='select-arrow'></span>");
    var val = $(this).children("option:selected").text();
    $(this).next(".selecttext").text(val);
    $(this).change(function(){
      var val = $(this).children("option:selected").text();
      $(this).next(".selecttext").text(val);
    });
  });
});
```

so for all the select it automatically wraps with div and after that the 2 spans are placed.
So when i change the value on the 1 drop down for the first time the values of the 2nd drop down is changed .
When i again change the value of the 1 drop down the 2 drop down values does not reset to the default value.
Because the span hold the value of the previously selected value.. How can i overcome this.

Comment: you should explain all the html in  http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: It involves Database to populate all the four drop downs so i will not be able to explain in jsfiddle.. as it takes more time to implement the same.

Comment: what is the actual question?. your question header is change the style of css but your content doesn't like that..

Comment: I need to change the style of the dropdown a different look than the regular drop downs.. I am having css file and i am trying to add them through jquery as mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("select").each(function(){
    $(this).wrap('<div class="selectbox"/>');
    $(this).after("<span class='selecttext'></span><span class='select-arrow'></span>");
    var val = $(this).children("option:selected").text();
    $(this).next(".selecttext").text(val);
  });
    $("select").change(function(){
      var val = $(this).children("option:selected").text();
      $(this).next(".selecttext").text(val);
    });
});
```

Comment: I have got a solution to my problem : We can add a div id and span id dynamically for each drop down and onchange of each drop down we can clear the span text to default value from the previously selected value.